# How is image storage typically handled during local development in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I have recently started my first project in Rails(5), coming from a PHP/Wordpress background (so bear with me). I plan on hosting the production site on Heroku, and I know that people will typically use a service like S3 to host uploaded images.

My question is: do you usually set up a connection to S3 while still in local development? I'm trying to keep costs low, so I'm wondering if there is another option while still in dev. And if there is another option, is it a huge hassle to switch over to S3 for production?

I'm sorry if these questions are extremely stupid, I just cannot find information on this; maybe I'm wording my questions poorly. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, you are using a gem for file uploading/image processing like `Paperclip`, `CarrierWave` etc. And you are configuring them different, per environment: S3 storage for `staging`|`production` and local file storage for `test`|`development`

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the response! I was planning on using a gem that utilizes direct upload, so I'd just set different settings in the environment config. Cool! Do you know if people will typically use a free option for local dev by any chance?

Comment: Didn't understand last question.

Comment: Sorry Pavel, thanks for your patience. While still in development on a local machine, do developers still use and pay for a service like S3 to host images? Or do they use a free solution, and only pay for S3 in the production environment?

Comment: Don't know about the others, I'm using S3 in dev too. The most of S3 charge is for requests, so storage itself is very cheap.

Comment: Good to know, thank you very much. I researched it a bit more and you're right, we're talking pennies rather than dollars. I think my boss will be cool with that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the development environment, you can use the file system for storage and S3 for production. Below CarrierWave config to implement this.

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.test? ||  Rails.env.development?
    config.storage = :file
  else
    config.storage = :fog
  end

  # Configuration for Amazon S3 should be made available through an Environment variable.
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    region:                ENV['AWS_S3_REGION']
  }

  config.fog_directory  = ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME']
  config.fog_public     = true  
end
```

Really I'm using S3 for development too because its very low cost. Too sometimes needs to use specific methods of S3 storage, like file privacy.

Comment: Thanks for the example Alex! That's interesting that you use it for dev too, I'll have to look at the costs more closely.